# Get the Azure AD B2C Application client id in the custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Hi the custom policy gets called with the client id of the B2C app

https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_POLICY&client_id=THE-CLIENT-ID-I-WANT

How can I access this in the policy, i thought this would be hard coded to the client_id claim but I dont think it is

Its only returned as default as the aud claim but again I dont see that in the custom policy

Thanks

Comment: hey looks like you can use {OIDC:ClientId} to grab the claim into an input claim, need to investigate more if i can persist this claim

Anyone know other {variables that exist} or where I can find a full list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok its a bit of a work around but I tried with a standard UserJourneyContextProvider technical profile and this didnt work

so to get the client id as a claim I did the following

Create an orchestration step

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="ClientIdFromOIDC-JC" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Get-ClientID-FromOIDC"/>
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Then create a RESTFUL technical profile which will call a Function App passing the OIDC with the {OIDC:ClientID}

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Get-ClientID-FromOIDC">
  <DisplayName>Get-ClientID-FromOIDC</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Name="Proprietary"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">--FUNCTION APP URL--</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" PartnerClaimType="client_id"/>
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id"/>
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And then finally create a function app which accepts the client id from the querystring and returns it with the correct format for B2C to identify

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    // parse query parameter
    string client_id = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                       .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "client_id", true) == 0)
                       .Value;

    return req.CreateResponse<ResponseContent>(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResponseContent
    {
        version = "1.0.0",
        status = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
        client_id = client_id
    }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");
}

class ResponseContent {
    public string version;
    public int status;
    public string client_id;
}
```

You will now get the B2C application client_id as a claim in the claim bag so you can do what you want with it now

Answer (score 2):

**You need to add the following into the metadata tag of technical profile:**

`<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>`

For more on this. See here: [OAUTH-KV Claims Resolver in AAD B2C does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008134/oauth-kv-claims-resolver-in-aad-b2c-does-not-work)

**Then use:**

`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ClientId" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>`

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview