# prompt and save new claims for an application using the same Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we have an application "A" where users must enter an attribute (specific for this application "A") that is stored in Claim "ClaimA" and

an new application "B" where users must enter an attribute (specific for this application "B") that is stored in Claim "ClaimB" and

We are using custom policies and have common Base and Extension Policies. We have created CombinedSignUpSignPolicy-A and CombinedSignUpSignPolicy-B

Problem we are facing is :- New Claims are being asked even on Sign-In(User has already provided the value on SignUp). We are expecting New Claims to be asked while SignUp and when they don't exist. But it seems it is always executing this step.

I have followed the solution mentioned here 
[How to prompt for new claims for a new application using the same Azure AD B2C tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566913/how-to-prompt-for-new-claims-for-a-new-application-using-the-same-azure-ad-b2c-t/46576407#46576407)

Here is our UserJourney:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="WorkAccountExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="WorkAccountExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="WorkProfile" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_ClaimA</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedApplicationARegistrationExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-A" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Enterprise" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Enterprise" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>             
          <Value>WorkAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
      in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
         from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
         (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

and

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-A">
      <DisplayName>Application A Registration</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>

        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ClaimA" Required="true" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>

    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are needing to skip the fourth orchestration step, then `ExecuteActionIf` should be set to `true`:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>extension_ClaimA</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAssertedApplicationARegistrationExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-A" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

i.e. Skip the orchestration step if the **extension_ClaimA** claim does exist.

Comment: after making it to true, is the order correct or should be moved to Step 7?.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you move it later in the user journey.