# OAUTH-KV Claims Resolver in AAD B2C does not work

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to use the `OAUTH-KV` **Claims Resolver** to extract the value of a parameter named `foo` passed to an AAD B2C custom policy `authorize` endpoint as a claim, also named `foo`.

The `foo` `ClaimType` is defined as

```
<ClaimType Id="foo">
  <DisplayName>Foo debug claim</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

and the `TechnicalProfile` as

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccount-Register">
  <DisplayName>Register</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.registration.prescribedfirm</Item>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="foo" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:foo}" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="foo" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

However the value for `foo` is displayed as `{OAUTH-KV:foo}` rather than the actual value passed.

I believe I have followed the instructions from the documentation.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

---

## EDIT

The documentation relating to claim resolvers was updated 25-01-2019 here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview, according to which this should work.

I am unable to get **any** claim resolver to show anything except the markup, i.e. `{Context:CorrelationId}`, `{OIDC:LoginHint}`, etc.

Does anyone know if there are any magic `Metadata` values required to make this work?

I am sure I am doing something wrong, leaving something out, but am unable to figure out what.

Any helpful pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Claims resolvers only work in specific Technical Profiles, those being REST API and SelfAsserted (combined sign up and sign in content definition at the orchestrations step). It explicitly only works in the examples provided in the document.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593754/query-string-claims-resolver-with-saml2-b2c-custom-policy/65731907#65731907)

You have to configure the **metadata** of the technical profile and set the **AlwaysUseDefaultValue** property of the input claim.

Comment: Adding `<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>` was what did it. It is hidden in the documentation at the end of this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on already existing AD B2C custom policy extension XML which deployed in production, and this is how the ClaimProvider is configured there:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Self-Asserted ReadQueryParameters</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAssserted-ReadQueryParameters">
      <DisplayName>Self-Asserted ReadQueryParameters</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="foo" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:foo}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```