# Query String Claims Resolver with SAML2 B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to read a custom query string parameter from a SAML2 relying party request?.

Using the {OAUTH-KV:any custom query string} does not work.

example:

https://mytest.b2clogin.com/mytest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TEST_SAML/samlp/sso/login?myparameter=true

I need to read the "myparameter" value into a claim.

Comment: Please refer this similar question w.r.t [claim resolvers possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008134/oauth-kv-claims-resolver-in-aad-b2c-does-not-work)

Answer (score 5):

Hope you are trying to do the following:

```
<InputClaims>
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:name}" />
 </InputClaims>
```

To get the value from the query string you have to configure the **metadata** of the technical profile and set the **AlwaysUseDefaultValue** property of the input claim like the following:

```
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
```

and

```
 <InputClaims>
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:name}" />
 </InputClaims>
```

Comment: This works only for OIDC or OAuth2, but not for SAML. It is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#oauth2-key-value-parameters).
I am trying to do the same but I can not find any way to share values using query parameters in SAML.